# Get all possible combinations of distributing x*n balls into n boxes

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out how to get all `combinations` of putting `x*n` balls into `n` boxes.

There should be the same number of balls in each box.

If it was about putting n balls into n boxes, the result would be `n!` and the pseudocode:

```
for b1 in set:
   for b2 in set-b2:
      for b3 in set-b2-b3:
          results.append(b1,b2,b3,b4)
```

How can I get this way combinations of `x*n` instead of `n` balls so in one box there is `x` balls exactly?

Comment: This is a math question and belongs to math.se. The answer is $(xn)!/x!^n$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Counting the number of combinations is math, but an algorithm to generate them is CS.

Comment: Generating them is even easier using the trivial recursive approach. The difficult part is counting the number of solutions.